# How to send a string with quotemarks in the RequestBody?

Tags: java, json, angular, rest

I have the following API-method:

```
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<?> partialProjectUpdate(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody EntryStatus status) throws DailyEntryNotFoundException {
    return dailyEntryService.partialDailyEntryUpdate(id, status);
  }
```

`EntryStatus` is an enum:

```
public enum EntryStatus {
  OPEN,
  PROGRESS,
  CHECKED,
  BOOKED,
  UNAVAILABLE;

  private static Map<String, EntryStatus> namesMap = new HashMap<String, EntryStatus>(3);

  static {
    namesMap.put("OPEN", OPEN);
    namesMap.put("PROGRESS", PROGRESS);
    namesMap.put("CHECKED", CHECKED);
    namesMap.put("BOOKED", BOOKED);
    namesMap.put("UNAVAILABLE", UNAVAILABLE);
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static EntryStatus forValue(String value) {
    return namesMap.get(value);
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String toValue() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, EntryStatus> entry : namesMap.entrySet()) {
      if (entry.getValue() == this)
        return entry.getKey();
    }

    return null; // or fail
  }
}
```

I call the method in typescript like this:

```
partialUpdateDailyEntry(dailyEntry: DailyEntry, status): Observable<any> {
    const statusName: string = status.name;
    return this.http.patch(BASE_URL + dailyEntry.id, statusName, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleService.error)
      );
  }
```

`statusName` is a string, but the problem is that its getting sent without quotemarks via JSON. The `RequestBody` is for example `OPEN` instead of `"OPEN"` which gives me the following error:

```
JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'OPEN': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null').
```

As stated thats caused by the fact that the string is sent without quotemarks.

I could fix that problem by adding the quotemarks manually to `statusName` like this:

```
const statusName: string = '"' + status.name + '"';
```

But that cant be the proper solution, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
public enum EntryStatus{
    OPEN,
    PROGRESS,
    CHECKED,
    BOOKED,
    UNAVAILABLE;
}
```

Comment: I get the same error with this. It still expects a `String` in the `RequestBody`, so the `RequestBody` still needs to have quotemarks which it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the header that you are sending `JSON`, but `"OPEN"` is not a valid JSON value.

You should either change your headers:

```
this.authService.setHeaders('text/plain')
```

Or change how you send it:

```
this.http.patch(BASE_URL + dailyEntry.id, { status: statusName});
```

And change your java backend to handle to receive the object and read the status

Or stringify it before sending it:

```
const statusName: string = JSON.stringify(status.name);
```

Comment: But if i send `"OPEN"` in the Body as JSON with postman like [this](https://gyazo.com/d66bfd0ccc61c2da4b24961e3c5da190) it works, so shouldnt it be a valid JSON value?

Comment: @M.Dietz if it is a json so you have to send it with double quotes

Comment: @M.Dietz Postman probably sends `"OPEN"`, I guess the angular `HttpClient` only uses `JSON.stringify` when the passed body argument is not a string. You are telling the `HttpClient` you are going to send a JSON, but then you don't ;). I added a third option you could try though, this adds quotes

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could put

namesMap.put("OPEN", OPEN);

as

namesMap.put("\"OPEN\"", OPEN);